# Highcharts errorbar with corsshairs

Tags: highcharts

I try to use a horizontal crosshair as some kind of auxiliary line to compare the upper and lower endpoints of the errorbars.

From a statistical point of view it is some kind of virtual significance test by comparing the confidence intervals.

My problem is that given a column chart I am not able to reach the lower endpoint of the errorbars with the crosshair.

Here [is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohkw3su8/) (simplified demo from Highcharts).

```
var chart;
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature vs Rainfall'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }],
    yAxis: [{ 
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }
    }],
    tooltip:{
        crosshairs: [false, {color: 'red'}],
        formatter: function(){
            return false;
        }

    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    }, {
        name: 'Rainfall error',
        type: 'errorbar',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [[42, 51], [66, 73], [90, 110], [128, 136], [140, 150], [171, 179], [135, 143], [142, 149], [204, 220], [189, 199], [90, 110], [52, 56]],
    }]
  });
});
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure how this will tell you anything, unless your error bars are all centered at the same y value. And if that's the case, I would think it would be better to show a single reference line using a plotLine, or a line series formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error bars are paths in SVG, so there's no such thing like lower/higher part of it. If you check highcharts.src.js file and search for `drawCrosshair`, you will find method responsible for rendering crosshair. As you can see, there is line:

```
pos = (this.chart.inverted != this.horiz) ? point.plotX : this.len - point.plotY;
```

Which takes `point.plotY` to get position of the crosshair. In error bars plotY is top of the point. If you replace `point.plotY` with `point.lowPlot` (only for error bars!) then you will render crosshair on the bottom part of the error bar.